# How to check if document load completed in MIT AI2?

Tags: android

I'm a web developer but want to craft application that sends commands to a web server from android. I just created a web browser and loaded web page. 
But I want to know if document loaded completely. 
I searched all blocks but couldn't find that event handler.
If anyone of you used this platform to craft android application and have some idea please save my life. Thanks.

I want to check if page load is complete or not in andorid.

Comment: so what is the problem? elaborate

Comment: read last line in question @A.easazadeh